# Draw line between table records in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Assume I am querying a table from `psql` like this:

```
select * from sometable ;
```

With my current settings I would get something like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  value  |  value  |  value  |
|  value  |  value  |  value  |
|  value  |  value  |  value  |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Since I often share interactive psql shells (where I need to make queries on the fly) with people not from the informatics area, for readability reasons I would like an output like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  value  |  value  |  value  |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  value  |  value  |  value  |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  value  |  value  |  value  |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

That is, I would like a line between each record, because when I show **long text values** and they are **wrapped** (little tip: use `\pset format wrapped` to obtain this wrapping), it may become difficult to **distinguish** between different records.

Do you know how to achieve this on psql? I tried different options, e.g setting the `recordsep` character, with no success.

Comment: Perhaps you should find another tool for such users.  PSQL isn't really designed for people who would be so offput but such formatting.

Comment: Many thanks @GordonLinoff I was already thinking about this, but since apparently this was the only thing which was slightly confusing for them, I wanted to understand whether I could save some effort finding the right setting in psql rather than finding another tool. In fact, if I don't manage to solve this, I may ask them to just accept the current psql formatting. But it is still a good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Not a direct solution to your question, but you may be able to use the html format along with `\g | ...` (pipe the results to stdout). For instance, `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 \g | x-www-browser "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0 <&0)"` opens the results in a new vivaldi tab. I could not get this to work with firefox though, and having a browser tab popup every time might get annoying in an everyday workflow. Edit: it might be better to use a tmp file, looks like there's a size limit to data URLs (`select generate_series(1, 1000)` stops at 415 for me, while `(1, 10000)` outright fails).

Comment: Hi @Marth many thanks, could you make an example with the table I used in the question?

Comment: @Marth many thanks again, using your idea I have found a way to obtain exactly what I want :)

Comment: @Marth at the end I have found the perfect combination between the reliability of your browser-based approach and the simplicity of my terminal-only approach, see my second answer below :) Thanks again, without your answer I wouldn't have managed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And now I have found an even better answer, still building on [Marth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67504356/6854564) and on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67551358/6854564).

This is an example of a query result using this approach (there were sensitive data, so I replaced most characters with the X letter).

[image: Big query result example]

I think this is ideal, easier to use and more reliable than my previous answer.

It is also partially similar to Marth's answer, but with the key difference that no GUI browsers are needed and everything stays in the same terminal where psql is executed.

### Prerequisite

First you need to install the [w3m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m) tool, which can read HTML pages and can also be used like a pager (like `less`, but with specific support for HTML).

In many Linux distros you can install it by just typing:

```
sudo apt install w3m
```

### First method (on the fly)

One way to do this on the fly is just `\H \g | w3m -T text/html` at the end of the SQL command. `\H` enables HTML output and the rest of the command pipes the output to the w3m tool.

For example a command like:

```
select * from sometable \H \g | w3m -T text/html
```

would produce a result like this:

```
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│column1│column2│column3│
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ value │ value │ value │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ value │ value │ value │
├───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ value │ value │ value │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
(3 rows)
```

You can also first get a normal output and decide afterwards that you want it more readable, then you just type:

```
\H \g | w3m -T text/html
```

and the last query is repeated but piped to w3m.

You can disable HTML output after seeing the table by typing `\H` again.

### Second method (default pager)

You can also avoid appending anything to your SQL commands by setting w3m to be your default pager.

In particular, if you type:

```
\H
\setenv PAGER 'w3m -T text/html'
\pset pager always
```

And from now the outputs of all queries will be piped to w3m without appending anything to the SQL commands.

### Benefits of piping to w3m

- Fancy and very readable output.
- Well separated records and columns.
- More reliable than my first idea.
- Perfect support for long and wrapped record values (instead of the manual workarounds of my first idea).
- It automatically adapts to the size of your terminal if you resize the window.
- Support for scrolling using a mouse.

### Tips and my personal configuration

This is my configuration when I want to use w3m for the output.

```
\H
\setenv PAGER 'w3m -T text/html -o confirm_qq=false -no-mouse'
\pset pager always
```

So I substantially use the second method described above, but I also add extra options for w3m:

- `-o confirm_qq=false` to prevent w3m from asking me "are you sure you want to quit? (y/n)" every time I press `q` after seeing a result;
- `-no-mouse` to disable mouse support. Although I partially like scrolling with my mouse, that prevents me from selecting and copying data to paste it in other apps, therefore I prefer to disable it and to scroll using `PgUp` and `PgDown` instead.

### A final note

This approach produces a very readable output, and it is very good in particular when running live queries together with other people, especially people who are not developers.

But in many situations, if data are easy to read and/or you do not need to show very fancy query results, the following approach would be quite readable and a bit easier to set up

```
\pset format wrapped
\pset border 2
```

This one is a less fancy and the distinction between multi-line records could be less clear, since no horizontal lines are drawn between records, but in many cases this could be just enough.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment above this does not directly answer the question, and might not be great solution in an everyday workflow.

---

An alternative to displaying the result in the console would be to show them in a browser.

Using `\H` (or `psql --html`) shows:

```html
# \H                   -- use \H to toggle back to normal mode
Output format is html.

# SELECT * FROM sometable ;
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th align="center">column1</th>
    <th align="center">column2</th>
    <th align="center">column3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">value</td>
    <td align="left">value</td>
    <td align="left">value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">value</td>
    <td align="left">value</td>
    <td align="left">value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">value</td>
    <td align="left">value</td>
    <td align="left">value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>(3 rows)<br />
</p>
```

---

We can pipe this to another program using `\g |`. However, piping to browser seems a bit finicky, so it seems easier to me to use a temporary file (note that there may be a better way to do this):

With a script (I used `/tmp/pipe_to_browser.sh`, you might want to set it somewhere in your `PATH`) like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=$(mktemp --suffix=.html)
cat - > $tmpfile

# Could use a specific browser too, eg `firefox`, if `x-www-browser` does not exist on your system
x-www-browser $tmpfile
```

```
# SELECT * FROM sometable \g | /tmp/pipe_to_browser.sh
```

opens a new tab showing something like
[image: rendered html]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [answer by Marth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67504356/6854564) I have found a way to obtain exactly that output.

### Configuration

I created a Python script attached at the end of the answer.

I gave it a short name, I called it `ftab` (fancy table).

The script just detects an existing horizontal line in the table (by default there is always at least one, between headers and values) and prints that horizontal line after each record.

The last two lines of the output are printed as they are because, with the default settings, the last two lines are just a line summarizing the total number of records and a blank line.

The script can be conveniently stored in a folder included in the `PATH` environment variable, and it can be made executable e.g. by running:

```
chmod +x ftab
```

I also suggest that you make the script file non-writeable, otherwise you can accidentally overwrite it and lose the code if you forget to put the pipe symbol `|` in your queries.

```
chmod -w ftab
```

### One way to use it

Now, if I execute a query but I or my colleagues think that the output table is not readable enough, I can just type:

```
\g | ftab
```

and the same query is executed again, but the table is typed exactly as explained in the question, i.e.

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  value  |  value  |  value  |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  value  |  value  |  value  |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  value  |  value  |  value  |
+---------+---------+---------+
(3 rows)
```

### Another way to use it

If I want, I can always see the table like this rather than the default way.

In order to do this, I just append `\g | ftab` at the end of each query.

For example:

```
select * from sometable \g | ftab
```

### If you need scrolling

If there are many records and you need scrolling, just append  `| less` as you would do in a terminal, e.g.

```
select * from sometable \g | ftab | less
```

### EDIT (supporting wrapped values)

Since I said that this feature was especially useful in the case where values in some columns were wrapped in multiple lines, I realized my first version of the Python script was not supporting this case correctly, so I updated it.

In particular, I modified the script adding a check to see if a value is wrapped in multiple lines, which is usually represented by terminating the string in a column with either `.` (in case the line is broken because it is too long) or with `+` (in case the line is broken because there is a newline character).

Therefore, in order to fully support the case in which output is wrapped, you need to:

1. Enable wrapping by typing:

   `\pset format wrapped`
2. Since using the piping the screen width cannot be detected anymore, you have to decide the width in terms of number of columns (it must be at least 70 columns for some reason). In my case, I realized my screen is usually 210 columns wide, so I type:

   `\pset columns 210`

Of course, I need to set up these commands earlier than my meeting, so that I am ready to just run the queries when it starts. :)

### The `ftab` Python script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3                                                                                                                                                                                                 

import sys

def outwrite(s):
  try:
    sys.stdout.write(s)
  except BrokenPipeError:
    exit(0)

rule=''
rulechars=set('|+-\n')

result = sys.stdin.readlines()

for line in result[:-2]:
  if set(line) <= rulechars:
    if rule == '':
      rule = line
      outwrite(rule)
  else:
    outwrite(line)
    if not any(x in line for x in ['.|', '.\n', '+|', '+\n']):
      outwrite(rule)

outwrite(result[-2])
outwrite(result[-1])
```